# Handling logging across scripts importing multiple modules

Tags: powershell

I have a module that currently overrides the in-built `Write-Verbose/Error/Debug` statements, this contains some custom code but also writes the message to a text file named after the calling script (utilising `$MyInvocation`).

This is imported into all my scripts. These same scripts also import other modules that also make use of the `Write-Verbose` etc.

Now, I want all the output to end up in a single text file named after the original invoking script. This works for any `Write-Verbose` etc. statements in the calling script, but as soon as it uses functions from other modules, that then becomes the "calling script" and so the `Write-Verbose` statements for that function end up in a different log file named after the name of the module file.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you utilize the `$Script:` scope modifier in the module, it should grab the name of your module instead of whatever it gets imported to.

Comment: I want all the logging to end up in a file named after the script (the script that loads other modules etc.). Right now I end up with multiple log files, for each module, and the script itself.

Comment: `$PSCommandPath` will grab the script name that imports the module.